# Refactoring Sass Keyframe Stops

Tags: css, sass, less, scss-mixins

I have a set of keyframe animations that targets HTML that looks like the following:

```html
<g class="container">
  <path class="one" />
  <path class="two" />
  <path class="three" />
</g>
```

with sass that looks like

```css
.container {
  animation: anim-container 1s infinite linear;
}

.one {
  animation: anim-one 1s infinite linear;
}

.two {
  animation: anim-two 1s infinite linear;
}

.three {
  animation: anim-three 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframe anim-container {
  0% {
    transform: ...;
  }

  2% {
    transform: ...;
  }

  5% {
    transform: ...;
  }
  ...
}

@keyframe anim-one {
  0% {
    opacity: ...;
  }

  2% {
    opacity: ...;
  }

  5% {
    opacity: ...;
  }
  ...
}

@keyframe anim-two {
  0% {
    opacity: ...;
  }

  2% {
    opacity: ...;
  }

  5% {
    opacity: ...;
  }
  ...
}

@keyframe anim-three {
  0% {
    opacity: ...;
  }

  2% {
    opacity: ...;
  }

  5% {
    opacity: ...;
  }
  ...
}
```

Is there an elegant way to abstract the keyframe stops into a mixin or function since they're the same across all keyframes?

Comment: Could you provide more information ? What is repeated ? Just the stop value ? (0%, 2%, 5%, etc..)

Comment: @AmauryHanser yes just the stop values